# Laravel store() Method Won't Submit Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel, so pardon me if this seems to be a foolish question.

I'm trying to create a form that creates a bank account, and I have two models named Team and AgentBank. My Team model has a one-to-many Eloquent relationship to AgentBank model.

The form below gets data from the Team model to supply the "team_id" input.

**agent-bank/create.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="dark-panel card p-3">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('agent-bank.store') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <select class="form-control" name="team_id">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Team</option>
                    @foreach($teams as $team)
                        <option value={{ $team->id }}>{{ $team->team_name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Bank</option>
                    <option value="bank1">BANK1</option>
                    <option value="bank2">BANK2</option>
                    <option value="bank3">BANK3</option>
                    <option value="bank4">BANK4</option>
                    <option value="bank5">BANK5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <input class="form-control" name="account_name" type="text" placeholder="Account Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <input class="form-control" name="account_number" type="text" placeholder="Account Number">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <select class="form-control" name="account_type">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Function</option>
                    <option value="func1">FUNC1</option>
                    <option value="func2">FUNC2</option>
                    <option value="func3">FUNC3</option>
                    <option value="func4">FUNC4</option>
                    <option value="func5">FUNC5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <input class="form-control" name="account_balance" type="text" placeholder="Account Balance">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn primary-button btn-sm mt-2">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'bank_name' => 'required',
        'account_name' => 'required',
        'account_number' => 'required|unique:agent_banks',
        'account_type' => 'required'
    ]);

    $data = $request->except('account_balance');
    $data->account_balance = intval($request->account_balance);

    $agentbank->fill($data)->save();

    return redirect()->route('agent-bank.index')->with('flash_message', 'Bank ' . $agentbank->bank_name . ' ' . $agentbank->account_name . ' ' . $agentbank->account_number . ' succesfully added to ' . $teams->team_name);
}
```

Is there perhaps a typo or wrong code in this method that makes it so it can't be submitted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It is problem of `name`. Add `name="bank_name"` in select attribute and try:

```
               <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <select class="form-control" name="bank_name">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Bank</option>
                        <option value="bank1">BANK1</option>
                        <option value="bank2">BANK2</option>
                        <option value="bank3">BANK3</option>
                        <option value="bank4">BANK4</option>
                        <option value="bank5">BANK5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: shame on me, i didn't saw that.. thank you, but now it got another error "Attempt to assign property 'account_balance' of non-object" and the problem line is "$data->account_balance = intval($request->input('account_balance'));", i'm trying to get the input value of "account_balance" and convert it to integer..as the table is set to accept integer value.. any insight? thank you :)

Comment: never mind, corrected the mistake..thank you for your help @jigneshsinh-rathod

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem samply change the input type of `account_balance` to number.

`<div class="form-group mb-2"> <input class="form-control" name="account_balance" type="number" placeholder="Account Balance"> </div>`